# Is it possible to keep websockets connected on Node.js server restart?

Tags: node.js, websocket

Using any technique, is it possible to keep the websocket connected when restarting Node.js server?

Answer (score 12):

No, not directly.  By design, an OS cleans up any resources owned by a process when that process shuts-down.  This is how the OS prevents resource leaks over time as processes start up and shut down.  So, when your server process shuts down, any sockets it still has open will get shut down by the OS.

The usual design solution for this is to code clients that automatically reconnect if they lose their webSocket connection when the client didn't intend to lose the connection.  This type of auto-reconnect behavior is built into socket.io (a layer that sits on top of webSocket) for this exact reason.

If you insert a proxy in front of your server, configured so that clients connect to the proxy and then the proxy then connects through to your server, then it might be possible to teach the proxy to auto-reconnect to the server in a way that the clients would not know anything had happened (as long as they didn't try to send messages while the server was down).  Of course, then you have the same restart issue with the proxy.

In some operating systems, it is possible to transfer ownership of TCP sockets from one process on the same host to another process.  So, I could conceive of a scheme (which I have not tried) where you could fire up a temporary process, transfer all the webSocket sockets from your server to this temporary process, then restart your server, then after the new server instance comes up, transfer the sockets back and then kill the temporary process.

Since there are multiple other reasons why a webSocket might be unintentionally disconnected, I think the client-side reconnect is a solution that covers both the server restart and many other potential things that could happen in your system and for which code has already been written.

Comment: I have already added reconnection code, but then user does not get a good experience.
Also as soon as we clients start reconnecting, the server's CPU usage and Bandwidth increases

Comment: @Chintan - It's unclear why the client experience would be any more bad with a reconnect.  Your server is going to be down for a bit so all clients are essentially off-line during the restart.  Nothing you can do about that unless you start using multiple servers and others are online during the reboot.  Yes, it will take a little more server CPU to reconnect, but it should be a very short duration and then back to normal.

Comment: I also want to achieve the same thing, but the problem for eg. there are `100000 clients` which are reconnecting, as soon as the server starts everyone tries to connect, and on each connection, we have 3 4 `mongo i/o operations`, which chokes our `mongo` because mongo is unable to handle so much parallel requests. Is there any way we can avoid those reconnection of clients on server restart?

Comment: @SaifAliKhan - I'd suggest you ask your own question and fill in a lot more details of your specific situation.  That topic is not identical to what was asked here originally and discussing your issue is not something that really fits in comments here.